# How to disable pylint report of "E1120: No value for argument if" when passing a *args as list

Tags: python, list, pylint, argument-unpacking

I have the following code section that triggers Pylint error "E1120: No value for argument if".

> framework/packages/create_network.py:79:21: E1120: No value for argument 'bridge1' in function call (no-value-for-parameter)

**Is there a flag for Pylint that can bypass this check for this specific case? I am looking for a solution that doesn't require changes in the code itself and is a parameter passed to Pylint.**

In my answer I will put the flag I am familiar with that is an annotation in the code.

### Description of the case

This happens when passing an unpacked list as values to parameters defined by name and not by *args.

The script passes a list

```
bridges = create_bridge(interface1, interface2)   # Returns an array of 4 values
routers = get_routers(*bridges)   # Unpacks the array and passes values to 4 parameters
```

And the function signature is

```
def get_routers(bridge1, bridge2, bridge3, bridge4):
```

Answer (score 4):

This can be solved by disabling the specific check for E1120 for the specific line that causes the issue.

In this case the code will now have a pylint disable comment above the

```
bridges = create_bridge(interface1, interface2)   # Returns an array of 4 values
#pylint: disable = no-value-for-parameter   # Disables the pylint check for the next line
routers = get_routers(*bridges)   # Unpacks the array and passes values to 4 parameters
```

I dislike this solution because it forces me to change the itself. I'd prefer to disable this check when running Pylint as an optional flag just for unpacking list to parameters.